# Cross Compile Ubuntu Raspberry

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Followed [this tutorial](http://hertaville.com/2012/09/28/development-environment-raspberry-pi-cross-compiler/) i installed all the mentioned toolchain. After i choose my appropriate toolchain "gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian" in ".bashrc" file. After i submit "source .bashrc" but "arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -v" does not work.

This is my row in ".bashrc" file:

[image]

This is my bin folder:

[image]

When i try to check it this is the result:

[image]

As required, the former command **echo $PATH**

> /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/v1sc3rr4k/Universita/Android/sdk/tools:/home/v1sc3rr4k/Universita/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/home/v1sc3rr4k/Universita/Android/android-ndk-r9d:*/home/v1sc3rr4k/rpi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin*

whereas the latter **ls -l**

> -rwxr-xr-x 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k  620076 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-addr2line
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k  644400 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-ar
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k 1085080 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-as lrwxrwxrwx 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k      23 feb 11
>   23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-c++ -> arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k  618316 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-c++filt
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k  572984 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-cpp
>   -rw-r--r-- 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k    2977 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-ct-ng.config
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k 2706116 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-dwp
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k   51540 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-elfedit
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k  574264 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ lrwxrwxrwx 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k      29 feb
>   11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -> arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-4.8.3
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k  571736 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-4.8.3
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k   20748 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-ar
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k   20684 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-nm
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k   20684 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-ranlib
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k  257872 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcov
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k 3631768 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-gdb
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k  574712 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-gfortran
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k  681964 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-gprof lrwxrwxrwx 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k      26 feb
>   11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld -> arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld.bfd
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k 1064504 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld.bfd
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k   10501 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-ldd
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k 3755040 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld.gold
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k  629292 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-nm
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k  769100 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-objcopy
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k  960268 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-objdump
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k     417 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-pkg-config
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k   90444 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-pkg-config-real
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k  644400 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-ranlib
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k  431804 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-readelf
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k  620716 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-size
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k  620300 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-strings
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k  769100 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-strip
>   v1sc3rr4k@v1sc3rr4k:~/rpi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin$
>   cd v1sc3rr4k@v1sc3rr4k:~$ ls -l
>   /rpi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin ls:
>   impossibile accedere a
>   /rpi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin:
>   File o directory non esistente v1sc3rr4k@v1sc3rr4k:~$ ls -l
>   /home/v1sc3rr4k/rpi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin
>   totale 22540
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k  620076 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-addr2line
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k  644400 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-ar
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k 1085080 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-as lrwxrwxrwx 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k      23 feb 11
>   23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-c++ -> arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k  618316 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-c++filt
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k  572984 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-cpp
>   -rw-r--r-- 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k    2977 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-ct-ng.config
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k 2706116 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-dwp
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k   51540 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-elfedit
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k  574264 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ lrwxrwxrwx 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k      29 feb
>   11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -> arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-4.8.3
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k  571736 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-4.8.3
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k   20748 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-ar
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k   20684 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-nm
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k   20684 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-ranlib
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k  257872 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcov
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k 3631768 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-gdb
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k  574712 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-gfortran
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k  681964 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-gprof lrwxrwxrwx 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k      26 feb
>   11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld -> arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld.bfd
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k 1064504 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld.bfd
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k   10501 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-ldd
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k 3755040 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld.gold
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k  629292 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-nm
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k  769100 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-objcopy
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k  960268 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-objdump
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k     417 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-pkg-config
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k   90444 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-pkg-config-real
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k  644400 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-ranlib
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k  431804 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-readelf
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k  620716 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-size
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k  620300 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-strings
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 v1sc3rr4k v1sc3rr4k  769100 feb 11 23:02 arm-linux-gnueabihf-strip

Update

Using Eclipse i am able to compile for Raspberry. It compiles right and the code works. But i am interested to understand how solve this configuration problem on Ubuntu.

Comment: This would've been much easier for all of us (yourself included) if you had pasted the *text*, instead of images. Anyways, care to translate that error message for us?

Comment: What is the output of these two commands?

    **echo $PATH**

and:

    **ls -l <your_bin_folder_path>**

Comment: @Jorge Torres I edited my question with the mentionend command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it. This is because your path only contains the 'hard float' or 'hf' version of the compiler:

arm-linux-gnueabi**hf**-gcc

But your test is trying to run the non 'hf' version of the cross-compiler, so when you try to check the version to see if the compiler is installed, note that the 'hf' is missing.

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -v
```

That's the name of the 'soft float' version of the compiler, which is not installed. If you run your check as:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -v
```

You should get a valid reply. This is the compiler that you should use form your console. Alternatively, you can also opt for installing the 'soft float' version of the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Good!
I'm currently use the cross compiler for the raspberry only in MS windows.
Now I can try in Linux using the tutorial linked in your message.